# Can i great a asp.net application and deploy it as a set up? in c#

Tags: c#

i am create a wpf application and i can see most of the toolbox component that i need are in asp.net, can i create a asp.net application and deploy it as a set up? C# i need a grid with paging and filter in wpf

```
x:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" KeyFieldName="PK">
            <Columns>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PK" ReadOnly="True" VisibleIndex="0">
                    <EditFormSettings Visible="False" />
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="AssetPK" VisibleIndex="1">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DocumentPK" VisibleIndex="2">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ModuleID" VisibleIndex="3">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="PrintWithWO" VisibleIndex="4">
                </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn FieldName="SendWithEmail" VisibleIndex="5">
                </dx:GridViewDataCheckColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DemoLaborPK" VisibleIndex="6">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
                <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="RowVersionIPAddress" VisibleIndex="7">
                </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            </Columns>
            <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
        </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. Are you asking whether it is possible to use an ASP.NET WebForms GridView on a WPF window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work on a WPF project, implement charts into wpf is better for you.
Many WPF Chart components are exist. Check the following links:

Commercial:

1- Devexpress.com
2- Telerik.com

Open source:

1- http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=wpf%20chart